# How to show icons conditionally?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a small logic, where depending on the API property should be rendered different icons.

The API sends 3 types of media_type:

- image
- video
- album

I just want to display different icons based on those 3 types.

In react.js I would do :

```html
{
 data.media_type==='image'
 ?
 <mat-icon svgIcon="image" aria-hidden="false"></mat-icon>
 :
 data.media_type==='video'
 ?
 <mat-icon>video</mat-icon>
 :
 <mat-icon>album</mat-icon>
}
```

How can I do similar in Angular?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) ([tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2#add-a-details-section))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular you could also have the same implementation. I will mention 3 methods below:

### Method 1:

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="data.media_type==='image'">image</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="data.media_type==='video'">movie</mat-icon>
<mat-icon *ngIf="data.media_type==='album'">album</mat-icon>
```

In this case when `data.media_type` is `image`, the image icon is shown and the other two are hidden. The same goes for the other icons as well.

### Method 2:

```html
<mat-icon>{{data.media_type==='image' ? 'image' : data.media_type==='video' ? 'movie' : 'album'}}</mat-icon>
```

### Method 3:

In your component you can also define a method that returns the name of the icon you want to be displayed according to `data.media_type`.

```html
<mat-icon>{{showIcon()}}</mat-icon>
```

`xxx.component.ts`:

```js
showIcon():string {
   if (this.data.media_type === 'image') {
       return 'image';
   } else if (this.data.media_type === 'video') {
       return 'movie';
   } else {
       return 'album';
   }
}
```

---

My most and least favorite would be `method 1` and `method 3`. In `method 3`, the method is constantly being executed in your template which is why I think it is not the most efficient method.

Comment: Hi @ilpianoforte, thanks for the answer. Cool, that looks better.
I am wondering is there any workaround, instead of having this *ngIf condition for all icons, just do it for the icon name, like: "<mat-icon>*ngIf="data.media_type==='image'" image; *elseIf "data.media_type==='movie'" movie</mat-icon>

Comment: @Greg I updated my answer. I think method 2 or 3 is what you meant.